# position edge labels using cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Due to the nodes and edges between nodes, the breadthfirst algorithm is positioning nodes in such a way that labels on the nodes are overlapping one another.  Is it possible to have the algorithm either position the nodes or the edge labels so they don't overlap, or attempt to minimize overlap?

Comment: Your http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: @xmomjmr - do you even know what cytoscape is?  Please refrain from commenting/voting if you aren't knowledgeable on the subject matter, thanks.

Comment: yes I know what is cytoscape.js and I know what is a clear cytoscape question with "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example", like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296927/cytoscape-js-pan-and-z-index-foregrounding-elements-on-click. Your question in it's present form does not meet Stack Overflow question quality standards → http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be interested in label autorotation for edges, planned for 2.4 and implemented in `unstable`.  As for the logic you'd like in the layout itself, it may be a too tight coupling of implied rendering behaviour to the layout.  Whereas things like `node.outerHeight()` can be taken into consideration directly and explicitly in layouts, this would rely on the layout assuming certain rendering behaviour.

I think there's a factor option for spacing the nodes farther apart in the breadthfirst layout, and if you want to discuss other new ideas like it I would be happy to discuss it in a ticket in the tracker.

Thanks

Comment: This feature is merged already - use the [`edge-text-rotation` style attribute](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/documentation/md/style.md#labels), e.g. `edge-text-rotation: autorotate`.